# Django's CreateView is not saving an object

Tags: python, django

I'm practicing Django's generic views, particularly `ModelForms`

These are my views and models

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField('date posted')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('user-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post_title
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post_title = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Title',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':64})
    )
    post_content = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Content',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':128})
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

**views.py**

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):
    fields = ['post_title', 'post_content']
    template_name = 'app_blog/post_save_form.html'
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm   

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PostCreate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.post_date = datetime.now()
        return super(PostCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

The view seems to work fine, not displaying any errors. However, when I check the Django admin page after submitting a form and saving a post, the post is not saved into the database for some reason.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: have you any form error?

Answer (score 7):

As I can see from your code you use

```
self.object = form.save(commit=False)
```

which mean that object will not be saved to database, but you can use it for futher processing. So you should use something like this:

```
self.object = form.save(commit=False)  # Not hit database
self.object.user = self.request.user  # Update user
self.object.post_date = datetime.now()  # Update post_date
self.object.save()  # And finally save your object to database.
```

Comment: small fix-  self.object.save(), not self.obejct.save(). But you answer is right.

Comment: @nnmware small fixes can be applied using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17835949/edit) functionality. Editing other peoples answers is encouraged. You get reputation-points for suggesting valuable edits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.instance.post_date = datetime.now()
    return super(PostCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```